# GCD serial queue with NSTimer, dispatch_sync doesn't wait for the NSTimer to complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

I'm currently trying make a `queueHandler` that takes an object array as input for executing drive commands on a simple Double robot. I'm currently trying to use GCD in order to serially execute my functions, but when I'm using `dispatch_sync` on my queue in won't wait until the `NSTimer` has run its course, but will continue to try and execute the commands from the next object in my array.

I have 3 functions, one which simply initializes an `NSMutableArray`(loadCommands) with 2 objects and runs the `queueHandler`, this is called when I toggle a switch. Then the `queueHandler` reads the variables from the objects(type, timing, queueNr) to determine what type of drive function will be executed and for how long. This I thought could be done in a switch statement, and I figured it would be great if the app could execute the function on the main thread(that is ok!) but it should wait until the `NSTimer` has run its course. I thought encapsulating the switch case with a dispatch_sync would solve this but it promptly skips to the next iteration in the loop and tries to execute the next function instead, which is drive backwards for 3 seconds.

When I test this with a single object in the array the command will be executed without trouble. I suppose I'm locking up the main thread somehow. Would perhaps waiting for a return value from the function in the `@selector` in the `NSTimer` statement help?

I've only played with Objective C for about 10 days, I'd appreciate any help I could get with this bit!

```
- (void)loadCommands {
    //create an objectArray and put 2 objects inside it.

    NSMutableArray *driveCommandsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]     initWithCapacity:4];

     //Command 1
    DRCommands *C1 = [[DRCommands alloc] init];
    C1.timing = 3;
    C1.type = 1;
    C1.queueNr = 1;
    [driveCommandsArray addObject:C1];
     //Command 2
    DRCommands *C2 = [[DRCommands alloc] init];
    C2.timing = 3;
    C2.type = 2;
    C2.queueNr = 2;
    [driveCommandsArray addObject:C2];

    //call queueHandler
    [self queueHandler:driveCommandsArray];

}
```

**Queue handler:**

```
- (void)queueHandler: (NSMutableArray*) commandArray {

//Now, I'm not sure what I'm doing here, I watched a tutorial that     
//solved a vaguely similar problem and he put a dispatch_async before the 
//dispatch_sync. I can't run the dispatch_sync clause inside the case
//statement without this. 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSLog(@"Inside handler!");

    unsigned long count;
    count = [commandArray count]; //retrieve length/number of objects from the array.
    unsigned long a;

     for (a = 0; a < count;) {
     //run the loop until all objects has been managed.

        DRCommands* myObj = (DRCommands*)[commandArray objectAtIndex:a];

        //create 2 serial queues.
        dispatch_queue_t myQ1;
        myQ1 = dispatch_queue_create("myQ1", NULL);
        dispatch_queue_t myQ2;
        myQ2 = dispatch_queue_create("myQ2", NULL);

        int queueID = myObj.queueNr; //retrieve place in queue (not really used yet)
        int timeID = myObj.timing; //retrieve the amount of time the command shall be run through the NSTimer
        int typeID = myObj.type; //type of command

        NSLog(@"Inside for loop!");

        if (queueID == a+1) {
            a++;

            switch (typeID) {

                    {
                case 1:
                    NSLog(@"inside case 1");
                    dispatch_sync(myQ1, ^{ //doesn't wait for NSTimer to finish, 
                                           //letting the Double drive forward for 3 seconds,
                                           //before resuming operations.

                        counter_ = timeID;
                        seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter_];
                        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(jDriveForward) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

                    });
                    break;

                }
                    {
                case 2:
                    NSLog(@"inside case 2");
                    dispatch_sync(myQ2, ^{

                        counter_ = timeID;
                        seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter_];
                        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(jDriveBackward) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
                    });
                    break;
                }
                //add more cases
                    {
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"Exited for loop, and count is %lu", a);
        }
    });
}
```

**Drive commands:**

```
//Go forward X seconds.
- (void)jDriveForward {
    shouldDriveForward_ = YES; //sets a condition which is recognized by a callback function to run the device forward.
    counter_ -= 1;
    seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter_];

    if (counter_ <= 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        shouldDriveForward_ = NO;
    }
}

//Go backwards X seconds.
- (void)jDriveBackward {
    shouldDriveBackward_ = YES;
    counter_ -= 1;
    seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter_];

    if (counter_ <= 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        shouldDriveBackward_ = NO;
    }
}
```

**Provided drive function from the experimental [API](https://github.com/doublerobotics/Basic-Control-SDK-iOS/blob/master/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/DRViewController.m) I'm using**

I'm using a "token" such as "shouldDriveForward_" inside the function driveDoubleShouldUpdate which is TRUE for the duration of an NSTimer. I must call my drive methods inside that function for the robot not to default to idle mode. So whenever it is true for X duration, the function for driving forwards or backwards is active.

```
- (void)doubleDriveShouldUpdate:(DRDouble *)theDouble {

    float drive = (driveForwardButton.highlighted) ? kDRDriveDirectionForward : ((driveBackwardButton.highlighted) ? kDRDriveDirectionBackward : kDRDriveDirectionStop);
    float turn = (driveRightButton.highlighted) ? 1.0 : ((driveLeftButton.highlighted) ? -1.0 : 0.0);
    [theDouble drive:drive turn:turn];

    //below are custom functions
    //The NSTimer I'm using keep the BOOL values below TRUE for X seconds, 
    //making the robot go forward/backward through this callback  
    //method, which I must use
    if(shouldDriveForward_ == YES) {
        [theDouble variableDrive:(float)1.0 turn:(float)0.0];
    }
    if(shouldDriveBackward_ == YES) {
        [theDouble variableDrive:(float)-1.0 turn:(float)0.0];
    }

}
```

Comment: The NSTimer itself executes asynchronously - calling the target method when the timer expires. The call to `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` returns immediately after it has scheduled the timer.  You can use a dispatch semaphore to control your execution - release the semaphore in the NSTimer target. See the iOS concurrency programming guide

Comment: Even better is a serial dispatch queue although you will still need to use something like a semaphore to block until the timer expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're kind of jumbled up here with the combination of GCD and `NSTimer`. There's nothing to say they can't be intermixed, but an all-GCD approach might be easier to get your head around. I think I've discerned the gist of what you're trying to do here, and hacked something together that might be helpful. I've put [the whole project up on GitHub](https://github.com/ipmcc/SOExamples/tree/master/robotdriving), but here's the meat of it:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, DRCommandType) {
    DRCommandUnknown = 0,
    DRCommandTypeForward = 1,
    DRCommandTypeBackward = 2,
};

@interface DRCommand : NSObject
@property DRCommandType type;
@property NSTimeInterval duration;
@end

@implementation DRCommand
@end

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *commandNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *secondsRemainingLabel;

@property (strong, atomic) DRCommand* currentlyExecutingCommand;
@property (copy, atomic) NSNumber* currentCommandStarted;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do an initial UI update
    [self updateUI];
}

- (IBAction)loadCommands:(id)sender
{
    DRCommand *C1 = [[DRCommand alloc] init];
    C1.duration = 3.0;
    C1.type = DRCommandTypeForward;

    DRCommand *C2 = [[DRCommand alloc] init];
    C2.duration = 3.0;
    C2.type = DRCommandTypeBackward;

    [self handleCommands: @[ C1, C2 ]];
}

- (void)handleCommands: (NSArray*)commands
{
    // For safety... it could be a mutable array that the caller could continue to mutate
    commands = [commands copy];

    // This queue will do all our actual work
    dispatch_queue_t execQueue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    // We'll target the main queue because it simplifies the updating of the UI
    dispatch_set_target_queue(execQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue());

    // We'll use this queue to serve commands one at a time...
    dispatch_queue_t latchQueue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    // Have it target the execQueue; Not strictly necessary but codifies the relationship
    dispatch_set_target_queue(latchQueue, execQueue);

    // This timer will update our UI at 60FPS give or take, on the main thread.
    dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (1.0/60.0) * NSEC_PER_SEC, (1.0/30.0) * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{ [self updateUI]; });

    // Suspend the latch queue until we're ready to go
    dispatch_suspend(latchQueue);

    // The first thing to do for this command stream is to start UI updates
    dispatch_async(latchQueue, ^{ dispatch_resume(timer); });

    // Next enqueue each command in the array
    for (DRCommand* cmd in commands)
    {
        dispatch_async(latchQueue, ^{
            // Stop the queue from processing other commands.
            dispatch_suspend(latchQueue);

            // Update the "machine state"
            self.currentlyExecutingCommand = cmd;
            self.currentCommandStarted = @([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);

            // Set up the event that'll mark the end of the command.
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(cmd.duration * NSEC_PER_SEC)), execQueue, ^{
                // Clear out the machine state for the next command
                self.currentlyExecutingCommand = nil;
                self.currentCommandStarted = nil;

                // Resume the latch queue so that the next command starts
                dispatch_resume(latchQueue);
            });
        });
    }

    // After all the commands have finished, add a cleanup block to stop the timer, and
    // make sure the UI doesn't have stale text in it.
    dispatch_async(latchQueue, ^{
        dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
        [self updateUI];
    });

    // Everything is queued up, so start the command queue
    dispatch_resume(latchQueue);
}

- (void)updateUI
{
    // Make sure we only ever update the UI on the main thread.
    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self updateUI]; });
        return;
    }

    DRCommand* currentCmd = self.currentlyExecutingCommand;
    switch (currentCmd.type)
    {
        case DRCommandUnknown:
            self.commandNameLabel.text = @"None";
            break;
        case DRCommandTypeForward:
            self.commandNameLabel.text = @"Forward";
            break;
        case DRCommandTypeBackward:
            self.commandNameLabel.text = @"Backward";
            break;
    }

    NSNumber* startTime = self.currentCommandStarted;
    if (!startTime || !currentCmd)
    {
        self.secondsRemainingLabel.text = @"";
    }
    else
    {
        const NSTimeInterval startTimeDbl = startTime.doubleValue;
        const NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        const NSTimeInterval duration = currentCmd.duration;
        const NSTimeInterval remaining = MAX(0, startTimeDbl + duration - currentTime);
        self.secondsRemainingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%1.3g", remaining];
    }
}

@end
```

Let me know in a comment if there's any part you'd like more explanation on.

Note: The other answer here has the command doing a `sleep`; my approach is fully asynchronous. Which approach is right for you will depend on what your commands are *actually* doing which wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: Sure. My assumption was that the `sleep` call was a just placeholder for other synchronous work, and not an endorsement of `sleep` for any particular purpose. If the workload is synchronous, then the `sleep` example may be an easier example to understand/adapt. If the workload is not synchronous, then my approach might be easier to adapt.

Comment: @ipmcc Thanks for the answer! What the commands really do is making a [Double](http://www.doublerobotics.com) robot drive forward/backwards or turn X degrees. Driving forward or backwards will require a function to be called in a callback function called driveDoubleShouldUpdate in the provided experimental [API](https://github.com/doublerobotics/Basic-Control-SDK-iOS) from their developer repo. Currently there exists functions to drive the robot based on UI input. My goal is to be able to specify the nature of the commands and then run them in after each other. I'll update the post to clarify

Comment: So I suppose my workload is synchronous. What I'm simple trying to do is to make the queue I'm supposed to use wait until the target drive function has finished running. 

I suppose a semaphore could act as a token and that could dictate whether a function should run or not, while the for loop continues to add commands to the serial queue, then simply executes them in order.

Comment: The commands I'm putting in my object array is basically defining a pattern that will run in sequence, making the robot drive a in a square for instance would require 8 commands, where 4 are 90-turns, and 4 drives the robot forward for say, 3 seconds.

Comment: I see; it looks like maybe what you want to do is have this VC implement `-doubleDriveShouldUpdate` to look at the `currentlyExecutingCommand` and use that to inform calls to `-[theDouble drive:turn:];`. The comments on their API aren't very good, so it's not entirely clear how they expect it to be used, but that's my best guess.

Comment: @ipmcc I've been having mail contact with them in order to clarify some of those things for that very reason. I'm currently trying to implement your suggestions. Given my clarification, I take it your approach is the most optimal one? 

Also the timer you declared appears to be hidden somehow? I get "local declaration of time hides instance variable". I suppose I can do a global declaration instead, from ViewController.h?

Comment: "Most optimal" is subjective; My approach should work, and is more asynchronous. It's what I would do. :)

Comment: @ipmcc Hi again, I just wanted to say that your solution worked out for me!! It runs very nicely and I now understand more about threading :) Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only need a single serial dispatch queue to which you will add your tasks.

I would start by defining a task class which implements your various commands - you can subclass if required.

**DRCommand.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DRCommand : NSObject

@property uint duration;

-(void) dispatch;

@end
```

**DRCommand.m**

```
#import "DRCommand.h"

@implementation DRCommand

-(void)dispatch {

    [self startCommand];

    sleep(self.duration);

    [self stopCommand];

}

-(void) startCommand {
    NSLog(@"Override this method to actually do something");
}

-(void) stopCommand {
    NSLog(@"Override this method to stop doing something");
}

@end
```

Then your run queue code will be something like

```
-(void) runQueue {
    DRCommand *c1=[DRCommand new];
    c1.duration=5;
    DRCommand *c2=[DRCommand new];
    c2.duration=7;
    DRCommand *c3=[DRCommand new];
    c3.duration=3;

    NSArray *taskArray=@[c1,c2,c3];

    dispatch_queue_t queue;
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);

    for (DRCommand *command in taskArray) {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [command dispatch];
        });
    }

}
```

Note that you would have subclasses of `DRCommand` such as `DRForwardCommand`, `DRBackwardCommand` and so on, each with appropriate `startCommand` and `stopCommand` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I recently updated my OP to better clarify how the experimental API I'm using is working. I using a "token" inside the function driveDoubleShouldUpdate which is TRUE for the duration of an NSTimer. I must call my drive methods inside that function, and I can control the duration of those commands through BOOL values that are unique for each function. So whenever it is true for X duration, the function for driving forwards or backwards is active.